# Null returned on querying content resolver for image absolute path

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am developing android app, where I pick up photo from gallery. In the method onActivityResult(), I have following codes:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if(requestCode==PICK_PHOTO && resultCode==RESULT_OK){

        this.picUri=intent.getData();

        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = this.getApplicationContext().
                getContentResolver().query(this.picUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index =  cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path=cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close(); 

    }
```

But the path returned from cursor is always null. What can be the possible reason?

Comment: How can you get something in it when you're not providing anything to it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the value of `uri` and you are retrieving intent result in `this.picUri` so you have to use that one

In `query` change `uri` to `this.picUri`

Like,

```
this.picUri=intent.getData();

String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = this.getApplicationContext().
                getContentResolver().query(this.picUri,  proj, null, null, null);
```

Comment: I had wrongly typed in the question. I changed uri to this.picUri. I am still getting the path as null. I am testing it in emulator. Can that be a cause?

Comment: i had picked up the photo from recents folder. When I picked up the photo from gallery, the problem was resolved. Can you explain why?